# Adesigns Calendarbundle events not showing after composer update

Tags: symfony, events, service, listener

I had the Calendar working correctly and the events showing for a while now but since i did a `composer update` yesterday the events are no longer showing.

When I put a `var_dump()` in the CalendarEventListener's constructor I can see that it is being called. The calendar is displaying correctly but the events are not showing and the loadEvents() function is not being called.

## app/config/routing.yml

```
adesigns_calendar:
    resource: "@ADesignsCalendarBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

## app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    calendar.calendar_listener:
        class:      CalendarBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
        arguments:  ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: calendar.load_events, method: loadEvents }
```

I've also tried putting the services.yml and routing.yml into `src/CalendarBundle/Resources/config/`

In the Symfony Profiler the it shows under the uncalled events.

```
calendar.load_events
0       "CalendarBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener::loadEvents()"
```

When I debug the events I get the following.

```
$ php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher

Registered Listeners Grouped by Event
=====================================

"calendar.load_events" event
----------------------------

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                           Priority  
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------- 
  #1      CalendarBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener::loadEvents()   0         
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies it wasn't an update issue but a data one. Some `NULL` dates had been entered which was causing errors.
I was only able to see the errors after re-basing and doing a `composer install`